# Vector orthogonal projection what's my error

Tags: vector-spaces

I've been recalculating the following problem for hours and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, please help me.

> We have the following figure:
>
> [image]
>
> By using orthogonal projection, determine the length of segment AD. (Segment BD and AC are perpendicular)

Here's what I tried:

$$\begin{align*}
AB &= (0,10,6) - (-2,8,6) = (2,2,1)\\\\
AC &= (4,5,5) - (-2,8,5) = (6,-3,0)\\\\
CB &= (0,10,6) - (4,5,5) = (-4,5,1)\\\\
CD &= \frac{CB \cdot AC}{\|AC\|^2} \cdot AC = \frac{(-24 + -15) - 39 }{\sqrt{45}} \cdot (6,-3,0)\\\\\\
&\text{(Does not make any sense from here)}\\\\\\
CD &= (-34.88, 17.44, 0)\\\\
D &= (-30.88, 22.44, 5)\\\\
AD &= \sqrt{-30.88} 
\end{align*}$$

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To project $CB$ in the direction of $CA$, you could use:
$$\|CD\| = \frac{CB \cdot CA}{\|CA\|} $$

and using $\|AD\| = \|AC\| - \|CD\|$, you should get $\dfrac{2}{ \sqrt{5}}$ after a bit of simplifying.

Comment: Alright, it gave me this answer once but I didn't trust myself since this problem is divided in 4 question. And on the next question they are saying that the length of CE = 2, this does not make much sense if we look at the picture